# Empty result set when matching NULL?

Tags: null

If I run a statement such as `SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE something=NULL` I will get an empty result set.

I know that the solution is to use `something IS NULL`. I also understand why: SQL interprets `NULL` as **unknown**, and it makes logical sense that if something is unknown, it can’t match something else.

What puzzles me is the meaning of the result set. I have always understood that you can’t *match* `something=NULL`, so why is is acceptable? It would suggest that under some circumstances, one might get a different result?

Alternatively, why does SQL not accept `something=NULL` as an idiom equivalent to `IS NULL`? It wouldn’t be the only idiom which doesn’t have a literal interpretation (such as `count(*)` vs `SELECT *`).

The question is: since `something=NULL` is not an error, does it mean something useful?

Comment: So if instead of a literal NULL you have `a=b` where `b` happens to be null, you want the equality operator to automatically take on the meaning of `IS (NULL)`?

Comment: @AndriyM Not necessarily. I’m not recommending anything of that sort, though a special case could be made for interpreting a literal `=NULL` that way _if_ it has no other meaning. However, I do see in your comment the seeds of a possible explanation: `WHERE A=B` may include nulls in either side, which should be omitted. `WHERE A=NULL` is a specific literal which simply forces the issue. Any chance of turning something like that into an answer?

Comment: I was merely pondering over possible implications of your suggestion and didn't really have an answer there. At the same time, you seem to have found one, and I'm perfectly happy for you if that's the case. Feel free to use the point I was asking about to expand your conclusions into an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare things to `NULL`.

`something=NULL` is not an error.

It is a Boolean expression that evaluates to unknown. SQL uses three valued logic. The possible results of a Boolean expression are `true`, `false` or `unknown`.

The `WHERE` clause only returns rows where the predicate evaluates to `true`.

Whilst comparing to a literal `null` with `=null` is rarely (if ever) useful it is certainly useful to be able to use an `col = something` predicate against a column which may contain `nulls` and the semantics of how `= something` operates against `null` are the same there.